What will be the local IP and remote IP while doing port forwarding in airtel Router?
I bought an unmanaged cloud server from the hosting company. My cloud Server IP is 50.21.182.217. It is hosted with Plesk so PORT is 8443. My local IP is 192.168.1.6 and my Router IP is 122.161.240.22. My cloud server IP is not accessible with my ISP (airtel) Is there any setting for this to make it accessible with my ISP (airtel)? I use the Cloudflare WARP agent to login to the cloud server. My website also requires Cloudflare Warp to log in or access. Can port Forwarding solve this problem? If yes, Please suggest the best setting.
Please Suggest the Best Option or Setting to make it possible. You can suggest the Port according to the best setting. I am new to cloud server hosting. I don't have sufficient knowledge about the port.
Router Settings Image:



My cloud server IP is not accessible with my ISP (airtel) Is there any setting for this to make it accessible with my ISP (airtel)?

That's very unlikely to be a setting that you can change on your router. It's going to be either an issue with your ISP or with the server's ISP (the hosting company).

Can port Forwarding solve this problem?

Usually not. "Port forwarding" is address/port translation, typically used when the target server is inside your network "behind" the router and does not have its own public address (i.e. when the server is borrowing the router's address). But in your case the server is 1) very much outside of your network and 2) does have its own Internet address, so "port forwarding" can do nothing useful for it.
